# error during connection to SQL Server using Micro Integrator 4.0.2

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-data-services-server

I have create Dataservice using Micro Integrator 4.2.0 to consume data from SQL Server 2012 ,it works fine in my local instance of micro integrator using this config :

```
<config id="mscrm">    
<property name="driverClassName">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>    
<property name="url">jdbc:sqlserver://********:1433;databaseName=********;integratedSecurity=false;encrypt=false</property>    
<property name="username">*******</property>    
<property name="password">********</property>  
</config>
```

but in the prod instance in kubernetes cluster ,i got errors:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS13, TLS12]". ClientConnectionId:17a956f9-6d42-484f-9cff-62af192ad2f7

        at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.description.config.RDBMSConfig.<init>(RDBMSConfig.java:39)
        at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.description.config.ConfigFactory.getRDBMSConfig(ConfigFactory.java:91)
        at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.description.config.ConfigFactory.createConfig(ConfigFactory.java:59)
        at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.DataServiceFactory.createDataService(DataServiceFactory.java:168)
        at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.DBDeployer.createDBService(DBDeployer.java:819)
        at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.DBDeployer.processService(DBDeployer.java:1182)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by removing TLSv1, TLSv1.1 from the java.security file in JAVA 17

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, \
    DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, \
    include jdk.disabled.namedCurves
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the following connection parameter to the connection string.

```
sslProtocol=TLSv1.2
```

Comment: Hi @ycr , Even i added sslProtocol=TLSv1.2 it still working only in the local Micro Integrator instance only .the problem is not resolved for Kubernetes Micro Integrator instance.

Comment: @OussamaNairi Is there a difference between the MSSQL driver and the Java version from local to K8S deployment?

Comment: @OussamaNairi Probably I read the error the other way around. In your local are you connecting to the same SQL Server? If not probably you have to downgrade the TLS version in Production. So try setting `sslProtocol=TLSv1` or just `sslProtocol=TLS`

Comment: we are using the same sql server even for production ,the problem that the .car generated working in my local machine but it generate error only in kubernetes env ,i think there is a config in deployment.toml file realted to TLS protocol that we have to add maybe ?

Comment: @OussamaNairi Nope, there aren't any changes in deployment.toml. The only explanation is the driver version you are using. Did you try the connection property I suggested in the last comment? `sslProtocol=TLSv1` or just `sslProtocol=TLS`

Comment: yes , i tried all ,when i generate .car file using those protocol (TLSv1,TLS,TLSv1.2 ) it works only in the micro integrator instance binary in my windows machine ,but when i give the .car file to product team to deployed in the micro integrator instance deployed in cluster K8s it throws the error.

Comment: I think i have to enable TLSv1 in deployment file as the documentation said : https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/mi-setup/transport_configurations/configuring-transports/

Comment: That's for the HTTP transport. Which is not related.